# How to obtain the exact solution of this first order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the following:

$$u_t + \frac{1}{1+0.5\cos x} u_x = 0$$

where $u(x,0) = \cos (x-1+0.5\sin (x+1)).$

My attempt:

I applied method of characteristics directly.

$$\frac {dt}{1}=(1+0.5\cos x)dx, \frac {du}{ds} = 0$$

From the equations, I obtain

$$x + 0.5\sin x - t = c$$
$$\Rightarrow u(x,t) = g(x+0.5 sin x - t)$$
where g is an arbitrary function to be determined.

By $u(x,0)$,
$$\cos (x-1+0.5\sin (x+1)) = g(x+0.5\sin x)$$

At this point, I can already feel that things may get hairy. Nevertheless, I tried to expand the sine term on the left hand side using trigonometric identities, but to no avail.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Your general solution $g(x+0.5\sin(x)-t) $ is correct. Are you sure that there is no typo in the condition ? A wrong bracket ? Where this condition is coming from ?

Comment: The initial condition is given as it is (as in, as part of the question). Unfortunately, there are no mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function
$$
\alpha(x)=x+0.5\sin x
$$
has a positive derivative everywhere on $\mathbf R$ and hence it is invertible. Then starting with 
$$
g(x+0.5\sin x)=g(\alpha(x))=\cos (x-1+0.5\sin (x+1))=\cos(\alpha(x+1)-2)
$$
we'll have that
$$
g(x)=\cos(\, \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(x)+1)-2\,) 
$$
for all $x \in \mathbf R.$ Maybe 
$$
\alpha(\alpha^{-1}(x)+1)-2
$$
can be simplified somehow (doubtful); if not, leave the answer as it is.

Comment: Your observation of $\alpha$ being invertible has been useful. While the exact answer is not a nice expression, at the very least the answer is exact. Thanks!